# How can I retrieve TCM URI of the currently logged in user in JavaScript code?

Tags: tridion

How can  I retrieve the TCM URI  of the currently logged in user to Tridion?

I am developing a GUI extension on Tridion 2011 and need to check whether a Component has been checked out to the currently logged in user or not. I plan on comparing the currently logged in user's TCM URI to `component.getLockedById()`.

I'm fairly sure I saw how to retrieve the currently logged in user's username somewhere when looking at Tridion's JavaScript files.

**EDIT**
I've found out one way to retrieve the username at least:

```
var username = Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance().getUserName();
```

Comment: Why do you need to check whether the items is checked-out to the current user? You don't usually need to do this, as you can just attempt to open the item. By choosing the correct OpenMode, you can control how the 'open' should behave if the item is checked out.

Comment: I'm writing a piece of code to make sure that a component is checked in. I get component information by using $models.getItem() and load the component if needed. I've noticed that using this method the component sometimes get checked out by the current user (if it was checked in before) and in that case I need to check it back in. My idea is to compare the currently logged in user to the checkout user and if they are equal, check in the component again.  

Trying to open the component could be a great alternative method. I will look into that!

Comment: Looks like you are simply loading items in wrong way.
"load" method has three parameters - "load(reload, openMode, suppressError)". The key is second parameter. By default it's set to "EDIT_WITH_FALLBACK". That means when you load the item, it will be checked-out if possible.
What you need to do - explicitly set openMode parameter to $const.OpenMode.VIEW, or use "staticLoad" method instead of "load". "staticLoad" by default loads item with VIEW open mode.

Comment: @BorisPonomarenko: Thanks for the information! That sounds like the best way to implement this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not had a chance to test this, but it is worth looking through the SDL Tridion 2011 Powertools project. There is a Utilities file at:

http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/Shared/Scripts/utils.js

That may help you. I think the line you may be looking for is

```
this._userSettings = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true);
```

I believe that is a standard piece of UI code rather than a custom PowerTools function

Comment: That's it! Thank you :) Code to get ID: Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"]