# How to get the user Id of the currently logged user in Tridion?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I implemented a Ribbon tool bar button in the Tridion. As part of that I need to loop through the some components, which requires a valid session.

To create a session in the Tridion I require a User Id. How to get the User Id of the current user(windows User Id)?

Will the following command help us to get the user info? If so please let me know the usage of the command.

```
getJsonUserSettings();
```

Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve TCM URI of the currently logged in user in JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171158/how-can-i-retrieve-tcm-uri-of-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-javascript-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way to get the User ID:

```
Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is returning the TCM ID of the user Id. How to convert it to the normal User Id? Please help me.

Comment: @User: What you mean normal user id?

Comment: @User: something like, `123` from the actual tcm id --> `tcm:0-123-65552`

Comment: Suppose if our `Windows user id is abc_xyz`. If that person is registered as an imporsonate user in Tridion for that user Tridion system is allocating one `TCM ID`. The command provided by you is able to fetch the `TCM ID`. But I require `Windows User Id`. I hope you understood the requirement. Please help me out.

Comment: One more command getUserId() is also present in the UserSettings class. How to use that command? As it is not an Static method...

Comment: @User: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear what do you have as input and what you are trying to get as output. But in most cases you should not have the same user configured as Tridion User and as impersonation user in Tridion. If you want to get windows user name out of Tridion User, there is a title (name) available in API. I'm not sure exactly how to get in the UI. From name you can get SID of a user by using windows API.

Answer (score 3):

In c# you can use `Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Utils.GetUserName()`

This will return the LOGIN name of the user, which you need - for instance - to impersonate.

I fumbled for a few seconds in Chrome's Console and came up with this for the user name - there may be an easier way to do it.

```
Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance().getUserName()
```

EDIT: As mentioned by Frank, this is a duplicate of [How can I retrieve TCM URI of the currently logged in user in JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171158/how-can-i-retrieve-tcm-uri-of-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-javascript-code)

Not a bad idea to start searching before posting...