# Anguilla - Get the version and user information

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a command button on the Ribbon Toolbar. When I select an component an click on "Display Info" button, an popup should open telling me about the latest version of the Component, Modified date, and the User who last modified it.

I do get the component with the following code:

`var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0));`

How can I get the other information from here.

Part 2:

When I try to see the JS code in Firebug, I see them in one single line. I am unable to put an break point on the execute function within my code.

Any suggestions on the above points. ?

Answer (score 6):

To deminify the JS, to allow you to add breakpoints, and also to allow you to use a JS console to inspect objects that are available, you can follow the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/DeactivateJSMinifier.

User information can be retrieved using the information at [How to get the user Id of the currently logged user in Tridion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891689/how-to-get-the-user-id-of-the-currently-logged-user-in-tridion)

Comment: It worked. Any pointers on Part 1 on how to get the version and user information

Answer (score 3):

I find that the only way to find anything with Anguilla is to use a JS Console like Chrome's.

Once you get the current item - like you do now - you can do stuff like:

```js
var version = item.getVersion();
var lastModifiedDate = item.getLastModifiedDate();
var lastEditorId = item.getStaticRevisorId();
```

getStaticRevisorId() gives you the Tridion URI of the last user to change the item, and you can then load this to retrieve further information from it.

Comment: item.getVersion() is returning "undefined" for me.

Comment: Infact most of the functions that are inherited from VersionedItem and Item class (ex: getCreatorDate(), getCreatorId()) are returning "undefined"

Comment: Could it be that the item is not loaded yet? Anguilla will load items asynchronously, so you need to set an event handler that runs when it finishes loading the object, something along these lines:
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", this.getDelegate(this._onItemLoad));